# How to check if a record is linked with two or more values in a left join

Tags: mysql, exists

In MySQL, I have a table of products connected with a different table with categories.

I often show the list by making a LEFT JOIN and GROUPING the results:

e.g. LEFT JOIN gives me:

`Name | Category`
`----------------`
`Cool cap | clothes`
`Cool cap | hats`

Then GROUPING by ID gives me 1 result.

**The question:** How can I show a list of products with `category='clothes' AND category='hats'`? Because the item won't show up because each category shows on a new line.

Comment: You can use two exists subqueries or two (`inner`, not `left`) joins.

Comment: Could you show me simple example? Because I tried using inners but it didn't work properly. =S

Comment: Edit the question and add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename ;` outputs and some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a GROUP_CONCAT to make them the same line and searchable.

Say you have a three way table. that has products, categories and a link table. First show all products with their categories as one table:

```
SELECT * FROM products
LEFT JOIN category_relations ON products.id = category_relations.prod_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON category_relations.cat_id = categories.id
```

Result:

```
Name     | Category
----------------
Cool cap | clothes
Cool cap | hats
```

Then let's make the category 1 line with GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(category SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM products
LEFT JOIN category_relations ON products.id = category_relations.prod_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON category_relations.cat_id = categories.id
GROUP BY products.id
```

Then the table will look like:

```
Name     | GROUP_CONCAT(category)
----------------
Cool cap | clothes, hats
```

However you **cannot use WHERE** to search a group_concat! You need to use 'HAVING' to search in a group_concat:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(category SEPARATOR ', ') AS allcategories
FROM products
LEFT JOIN category_relations ON products.id = category_relations.prod_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON category_relations.cat_id = categories.id
GROUP BY products.id
HAVING allcategories LIKE '%clothes%'
AND allcategories LIKE '%hats%'
```

This query will only show us the products with BOTH these categories. And will not show the products with just either one category.

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

You *may* need to do something like this:

```
WHERE ...
  AND ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM tbl
           WHERE Name = ...
           GROUP BY Name
           HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 )
```

For checking for exactly a certain list:

```
           WHERE Category IN ('clothes', 'hats')
           GROUP BY Name, Category
           HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

(There can't be more than 2 after the `GROUP BY`; this confirms that both are included.)

```
           WHERE Category IN ('clothes', 'hats', 'scarves')
           ...
           HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

would check for any 2 of those 3 (or all 3).

Comment: Thanks! But i need to check the actual values, not just how much.

Comment: see edit........